# Error 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' in browser with Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, module, pixi.js

Whi try in `script.js` to `import * as PIXI from 'pixi'` i'm getting such error in browser

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at script.js:1:1)

`index.html` looking like

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I was trying connet Pixi i different ways. In `package.json` I already have

```
{
  "name": "Terrain generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "pixi.js": "^7.1.0"
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you noticed all the related questions on the right side of the page under the **Related** heading?

Comment: Yes, I see them and I also trying adding ```module``` and nothing happens

Comment: Well the error is telling you that using `import` only works in a script loaded from `<scrypt type='module' ...>`. You didn't post any context for your `import` or any details about the HTML etc.

Comment: I add html code into main

Comment: OK thank you. That looks OK. Perhaps something is going wrong in your build/bundle process, or in deployment. You can verify that your "index.html" really makes it to the browser looking like what you posted, specifically the `<script>` tag.

Comment: I resolved my issue using ```pixi.mjs``` instead of ```pixi.js``` but i continue not to understand what i make wrong

Comment: Ah, well that's what I meant about the build I guess, but in the Node.js world, using `.mjs` as the extension instead of `.js` is like using `type='module'` in the browser. It tells it that the file is a module.

Answer (score 1):

Thats one way to use the legacy way of loading the library using script tags in your html file.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.2.1/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

And then in your script.js file you can use PIXI without import statement.

Comment: This variant also work

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
```

in your script.js file?

Cause I need extension .js to import in my project.

Comment: I was trying such but it didn't work